# How to set a variable in a labelname

Tags: c#, winforms, while-loop, textbox, label

in my project i have `8` *dynamic* `Textbox`es and `8` *dynamic* `Label`s, which were created in c#.
Now i need to read the text in it and insert it in a db.

My current script looks like

```
Label labelname1 = this.Controls.Find("label1", false).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
Label labelname2 = this.Controls.Find("label2", false).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
Label labelname3 = this.Controls.Find("label3", false).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
.....
```

Is it possible, to create a `while` *loop* with a variable like:

```
int i = 1;

while (a < 9)
{
    label Labelname+i = this.Controls.Find("label+i" + a, false).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
    i++;
}
```

When I take the `"labelname+i"` it's *not possible*, because it isn't a `string`.

Thank you

Comment: Web forms or windows form?

Comment: On windows form

Comment: if you stored them in an array when you made them, you wouldnt need to find them later

Comment: `this.Controls.Find($"label{i}" + a, false)` will create "label1", "label2", "label3", etc strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Extract method* then

```
 private T FindControl<T>(string name) where T : Control {
   return this
     .Controls
     .Find(name, false)
     .OfType<T>()
     .FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

and use it in a loop (it seems you want `for` one):

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 9; ++i) {
   Label myLabel = FindControl<Label>($"label{i}");

   if (myLabel != null) {
     //TODO: Put relevant code here
   }
 }
```

Same loop if you want to enumerate `TextBox`es:

```
 // textBox1..textBox8
 for (int i = 1; i < 9; ++i) {
   TextBox myTextBox = FindControl<TextBox>($"textBox{i}");

   if (myTextBox != null) {
     //TODO: Put relevant code here
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a List of Labels and try like:

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Labels>();

for (int i=1;i<9;i++)
{
    Label lbl = this.Controls.Find("label"+i.ToString(), false).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
   labels.Add(lbl);
}
```

And if you want to access i Label you simply do:

```
labels[i] ...
```